# Array character holding more than expected

Tags: c++, arrays, char

I am confused about the code below... please clarify.

When I use this code:

```
#include<iostream>
  using namespace std; 
int main()
{ 
   char array[10];
   cin>>array;
   int i=0;
   while(array[i]!='\0')
      {
        cout<<array[i];
        i++;
      }
}
```

and give the input: `qwertyuiop` - 10 characters. It's output is `qwertyuiop` again.

But when I initialize the array as in the code given below, it gives the error that the string is too long for array! Explanation?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
char array[10]="qwertyuiop";
int i=0;
while(array[i]!='\0')
    {
    cout<<array[i];
    i++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your first example is a buffer overflow and the second won't compile because you're trying to stuff 11 `char` into a 10 `char` array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first code snippet works by *sheer luck*. You are entering 10 characters into an array that can only hold **9**: the last position is, in C style strings, needed for the terminating `0`.

It appears to work because of two (related) reasons:

1. You enter not *much* more than 9 characters. Try entering many, many more and the program will surely crash.
2. There must be, by chance, a zero in the memory right after this array on the stack. If there was not, your output loop would continue to print data until it runs out of memory or encounters a `0` anywhere else.

So this is technically a "buffer overflow".

The error in the second snippet is because your compiler knows you should not store exactly *n* characters into an array of length *n* -- it points out that there is no room for the terminating `0`.

Answer (score 3):

Here is an example of buffer overflow. Your input string rewrites some bytes after the end of `array`. But it's a run-time problem, and it can't be detected at compile-time.

The real problem of code is that the behavior of the program is non-deterministic. Sometime the program can crash, sometime not.

You really need a buffer of reasonable size (f.e. 100 or more chars), and use a methods of limited input.

Comment: So what you are saying that upto the 10th character that is 'p' in this case. My array will hold correctly. Now since cin automatically truncate the string but there is no space left for it to do so above, the programm will occupy adjacent memory. In Short this string will not be truncated ?

Comment: @user3800101: `std::cin` doesn't automatically truncate anything. It writes past the end of the array and clobbers adjacent memory.

Comment: If it doesn't truncate automatically how the program has completed. Since the 'while' should never would have been stopped ?

Comment: @user3800101: Try typing a longer string (without spaces), you just haven't trashed enough memory to cause an obvious crash yet.

Comment: Of course, `cin` writes terminate '\0' character. And this character will be located after the end of `array`. Try the code: `char array[10]; char test[] = "test string";`. Input any 12 characters and then print `test`. It will be corrupted.